# How much coffee is too much?

Tags: ground-coffee, health, drip-brew

How much coffee is too much?

I know this would vary from individual to individual, depending on health, etc.

But I thought I'd ask this basic question on this format.

Per comment:
Here, "too much" == likely to harm one if done on a daily basis

Here coffee == brewed ground black coffee which I consider the 'standard' variant...

Comment: Define „too much“, please?

Comment: "too much" means here likely to harm one if done on a daily basis

Comment: Be careful of the accepted answer. The things that are likely to make "too much coffee" dangerous are specific chemicals that come from extraction. Caffeine comes most readily to mind, but coffee oils also contain chemicals which can raise cholesterol if consumed in excess. However, not all methods of brewing are equally successful at extracting these compounds. Dangers of coffee therefore depending on a person's general health, preexisting conditions, the details of the brewing method used to prepare the coffee, and the characteristics of the beans themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone has their own tolerance level for everything. None are the same.
In my case, if I, for some reason, drink 4 mugs of coffee in a single specific day, I kind of feel lightheaded and find myself unable to get some sleep until 6 am in the morning. So, I think my tolerance limit is 4 mugs.

It is up to you to find your own tolerance, but I think that it is not advisable to drink more than 3 mugs a day if you are like me.